# Confusion matrix result is different than results display by the classification report

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, confusion-matrix

I am training 8 different models on (binary and multilabel classification) and I come up with some discrepancy between the confusion matrix displays and the classification report.

F is 2020 sentences
and M is 1059 sentences

The NB model incorrectly classified most of the sentences belonging to F but the precision in classification report is > 0.70 maybe I am reading it badly?

```
Model name: Model_G_NB
Binary classification-----
precision_score : 0.3588210166595472
precision_score_micro : 0.44137707047742775
precision_score_macro : 0.5310365245899362
f1_b : 0.49411764705882355
f1_mi : 0.44137707047742775
f1_ma : 0.4352386639935162
recall : 0.7932011331444759
recall_mi : 0.44137707047742775
recall_macro : 0.5250659131068914
confusion Matrix

confusion matrice [[ 519 1501]
 [ 219  840]]
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           F       0.70      0.26      0.38      2020
           M       0.36      0.79      0.49      1059

    accuracy                           0.44      3079
   macro avg       0.53      0.53      0.44      3079
weighted avg       0.58      0.44      0.42      3079
```

As you can see precision for the class M is not really corresponding to the TP in the confusion matrix or I am reading wrongly the report ?

Reproductible example with Code line to obtain this classification report :

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from transformers import FlaubertModel, FlaubertTokenizer
texte = [ "Emaillé de références littéraires appropriées quoiqu'assez stéréotypées ('Erlkönig' de Goethe, 'The Raven' de Poe...), cette adaptation/mise en abyme du petit chaperon rouge ne cherche pas à faire peur, mais plutôt à instaurer une ambiance grâce à une photographie assez élaborée et un minimalisme bienvenu dans les effets spéciaux.
", "En tant qu'adulte, je n'aime pas le style des dessins, contrairement à mon fiston, mais en revanche, je tiens à souligner que l'intrigue et les rebondissements sont dignes des meilleurs romans à suspense que j'ai lus.
","Un court passage, mais une scène culte.
", "Son chef d'oeuvre reste Landcruising mais M.S.A.F.A.R.A est à peu prés aussi génial.
","j'ai 3 chats, dont une de 12 ans, mais grâce à ce livre j'en apprend encore sur eux !"]

ylabels = ["F","F","F","F","M"]
```

Embeddings

```
def get_flaubert_layer(texte):
  Model = ['flaubert-small-cased']
    flaubert, log = FlaubertModel.from_pretrained(modelname[0], output_loading_info=True)
    flaubert_tokenizer = FlaubertTokenizer.from_pretrained(modelname[0], do_lowercase=False)
    tokenized = texte.apply((lambda x: flaubert_tokenizer.encode(x, add_special_tokens=True)))
    max_len = 0
    for i in tokenized.values:
        if len(i) > max_len:
            max_len = len(i)
    padded = np.array([i + [0] * (max_len - len(i)) for i in tokenized.values])
    token_ids = torch.tensor(padded)
    with torch.no_grad():
        last_layer = flaubert(token_ids)[0][:,0,:].numpy()
        
    return last_layer, Model
```

```
    model1 = LinearSVC()
    model2 = GaussianNB()  # MultinomialNB() X cannot be a non-negative
    model3 = LogisticRegression()
    model4 = RandomForestClassifier()
    model5 = KNeighborsClassifier()
    model6 = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(150,100,50), max_iter=1000, activation = 'relu',solver='adam',random_state=1)
    model8 = XGBClassifier(eval_metric = "logloss")
    model7 = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()

    models = {'Model_SVC': model1, 'Model_G_NB': model2, 'Model_LR': model3, 'Model_RF': model4, 
    'Model_KN': model5, 'Model_MLP': model6, 'Model_LDA': model7,
    'Model_XGB': model8}
    
    features, modelname = get_flaubert_layer(texte)
    
    metrics = [ 'model', 'precision', 'precision_micro', 'precision_macro', 'rappel' ,
     'rappel_micro', 'rappel_macro', 'F_mesure', 'F_mesure_micro', 'F_mesure_macro']
    
    dic_metrics = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    dic_matrices = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    
    cv_splitter = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=False, random_state=42)
    
    print("-----------------------------------")
        
    for model_name, model in models.items():
        print("Model name: {}".format(model_name))
        y_pred = cross_val_predict(model, features, ylabels, cv=cv_splitter)
        print("Binary classification-----")
        
        cm = confusion_matrix(ylabels, y_pred)
        recall = np.diag(cm) / np.sum(cm, axis=1)
        precision = np.diag(cm) / np.sum(cm, axis=0)
        
        print("confusion Matrix\n")
        print("confusion matrice" , cm)
        
        print(classification_report(ylabels, y_pred))
```

Comment: Please use some [dummy data](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html) to make a [mcve]. SO does not work simply by throwing all our code here as is, and most of the code you post here, apart from the fact that it is not reproducible, is actually irrelevant to the actual question and hence not useful for possible respondents.

Comment: @desertnaut I put an example, since my data are a bit long

Comment: I cannot see any discrepancy the results seem consistent. See [Confusion Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix)

Comment: I talked about the case in the question, the precision for finding sentences belonging to the class F is  0.70  wheras the confusion matrix show that the model recognised only 519 ( 519/2020)  ; it seems false. I can send you my whole data if you want , the problem is that is there a way to send it via stackoverflow.